Are there any attempts to make translation models support ancient/extinct languages?
Are there any attempts to make translation models support ancient/extinct languages like Sumerian, Ancient Greek, Old Norse, Cornish, etc.?

Please, next time, share with us your findings so far. I'd encourage users to do a quick google search before asking this type of question.

I am not aware of any attempts at building machine translation for extinct languages specifically, but I would see this as a sub-field of machine translation for low resource languages. The techniques applied to low resource languages should also be applicable to extinct languages, as those are, naturally, low resource languages.
For an overview over machine translation for low resource languages, see Haddow et al., 2022: Survey of Low-Resource Machine Translation. This could be a starting point for you research.
